# Hammer.js v2.0 - Why panning is canceled when hitting the edges of the screen with a mouse device?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hammer.js

I'm trying to use Hammer's `panstart`, `panmove` and `panend` events in order to recognize drag-started, drag-moved and drag-ended events with a mouse device. However, whenever i hit the edges of the screen with the mouse cursor while dragging, I get a `pancancel` event, and my dragging operation stops. Why is it like that? Is there any way to disable such behavior by using the options argument? (I couldn't find anything in the official docs of hammer.js). Anyway, I would expect hammer.js to not cancel such panning operation in case that the source-device is a mouse.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please add the code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Did you manage to fix your problem? I am facing the same thing. Thanks